# How to redirect a subfolder to a different domain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I need to redirect a subfolder to another domain with the same subfolder name.

For example, I want to redirect the following url

```
www.domain.com/photo
```

...to another domain but same subfolder

```
www.domain2.net/photo
```

...using `mod_rewrite` in `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these lines in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# for HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.net/$1 [R=301,L]

# for HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain2.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

[You don't need `mod_rewrite` to do this](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite). In fact, avoiding it is simpler, more readable and thus more maintainable, and often faster.

Try this in `domain.com`'s root `.htaccess` file (or, more efficiently, in the domain configuration file itself):

```
RedirectMatch ^/photo/(.+) http://domain2.com/$1
```