# How to redirect a single subdir on the same website but with different domain name in Apache? (http://mysyte.com/us to http://mysite.us/us)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a problem with a strange htaccess configuration

I have a main domain name assigned to a website, let's say domain.com.

I use Joomla 2.5.19 and the site is set up to serve a multilanguage website.

All is working smoothly, and I can reach each language automatically: if you look for the it language, the system redirect you to domain.com/it, if you look for en language, the system redirect you to domain.com/en, and so on.

Now I have a special needing: I have bougth the same domain with different extensions to serve each language: i.e., I would like that the system will automatically redirect each language to the correcrt domain suffix (for example, domain.com/it must be redirected to domain.it/it, and so on)

I have assigned each domain name as Alias of the main domain.com in Apache config file

I have tried several solutions, also reading the mod_rewrite and .htaccess manuals, but I can't reach the goal, because I can't configure each domain.com/language/ Joomla subdir to avoid it loops on itself in infinite mode :(

Is there a solutions for that?
Thank you all in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to htaccess Redirect subfolder to another same subfolder name but different domain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864031/how-to-htaccess-redirect-subfolder-to-another-same-subfolder-name-but-different)

Answer (score 0):

tI have found a simple but working trick.
I'll explain it in the case you have two languages, EN and IT

At first, I have set up two differents Apache vhosts:
- one for the main domain mysite.com (it will serve the EN language)
- one for the second "laguage dedicated" domain mysite.it (it will serve the IT language)

The two vhost records are quite identical and pointing to the same physical path.

The only differences are:

1) the ServerName declaration, respectively equal to www.mysite.com and to www.mysite.it
2) the line that acts the redirection:
For mysite.com this line is:
RedirectMatch 301 ^/it/.*$ http://www.mysite.it/it/
*In this way the /it sub-structure is permanently redirected to the .it domain*
For mysite.it this line is:
RedirectMatch 301 ^/en/.*$ http://www.mysite.com/en/
*In this way the /en sub-structure is permanently redirected to the .com domain*
This simple architecture override the original multilingual structure, permitting you to serve any number of languages and correctly assigning them to the exact domain extension